# dockerでk3sを立ち上げdashboard起動でのエラー

Tags: docker, kubernetes

下記手順でk3sを利用しdashboardを起動しましたが、アクセスしてもエラーが出てしまいます。
dashboardの立ち上げ方はどの様にすれば良いですか？
macOSで試しました。

```
curl -L "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rancher/k3s/master/docker-compose.yml" -o docker-compose.yml
docker-compose up -d --scale node=3
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v1.10.1/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml --kubeconfig kubeconfig.yaml
kubectl proxy --kubeconfig kubeconfig.yaml
```

access: http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
Browser上に下記エラーが表示されます。

```
Error: 'dial tcp 10.42.1.3:8443: connect: connection refused'
Trying to reach: 'https://10.42.1.3:8443/'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こちらに回答が記載されていました。
[kubernetes/dashboard#3038 (comment)](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/3038#issuecomment-410743994)

記載通り下記の様に実施したところdashboardが表示されました。

```
$ kubectl --kubeconfig kubeconfig.yaml get pods --all-namespaces                                                          
NAMESPACE     NAME                                   READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-7748f7f6df-9sqs8               1/1     Running     0          17m
kube-system   helm-install-traefik-qx8lq             0/1     Completed   0          17m
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-57df4db6b-rd5lp   1/1     Running     0          5m55s
kube-system   svclb-traefik-fb554b487-5pvtw          2/2     Running     0          16m
kube-system   svclb-traefik-fb554b487-nvmg4          2/2     Running     0          16m
kube-system   traefik-5cc8776646-ssfbr               1/1     Running     0          16m

$ kubectl --kubeconfig kubeconfig.yaml --namespace=kube-system port-forward kubernetes-dashboard-57df4db6b-rd5lp 8443
```

access: https://localhost:8443